# What is the time complexity of this algorithm and how?

Tags: string, algorithm, c++11, data-structures, time-complexity

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i=i+2){
         for(int j=1; j<=n/2; j=j*3){
             for(int k=i; k*k<=n; k=k+1){
                  cout<<"YES"<<endl;
             }
         }        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My observation:
Here K is dependent on I .So the time complexity measure as like as bellow:

Suppose N=100 sqrt(n)=10

For:
i=1,  j will execute log3^(n/2) times,  and k will execute 1 to 10 =10 times

i=3,   j will execute log3^(n/2) times, and k will execute  3 to 10=8times

i=5,  j will execute log3^(n/2) times,and  k will execute 5 to 10=6 times

i=7,  j will execute log3^(n/2) times,and  k will execute 7 to 10=4 times

i=9,  j will execute log3^(n/2) times,and  k will execute 9 to 10=2 times

i=11, j will execute log3^(n/2) times and k will not execute so no time needed

So above equation like:

log3^(n/2)*10+ log3^(n/2)*8+ log3^(n/2)*6+ log3^(n/2)*4+ log3^(n/2)*2

= log3^(n/2)(10+8+6+4+2)
= log3^(n/2) {n*(n +1) } 
[1st N even numbers sum= (n*(n+1)] Here n=5 because first 5 even numbers so tot=5*(5+1)=30 = (10+8+6+4+2)

Comment: Where did you get `log3` from?

Comment: It will be `O(n^2.5)`

Comment: Trying to find the time complexity relation from numerical testing, especially with such small test numbers, is like trying to build the city of New York with a hammer. You are not going to get anywhere with any sane amount of work. Numerical testing comes *after* you derive the solution algebraically.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `j` loop is independent of the other indices, we can factor it out and simply multiply at the end. The value of `j` grows exponentially after each iteration of the loop, which means that the *number* of loops required is `log3(n/2)`. There are *countless* many proofs on SO for this simple loop form, so I won't derive it here.

Now for the two loops with `i` and `k`:

- The stop condition `k*k <= n` means that `k` grows linearly until it reaches `ceil(sqrt(n))`. Note that this loop does not run if `k = i` does not satisfy this condition.
- `i` increases by **2** instead of 1 each loop, so we can replace it with a variable `m` such that `2*m + 1 = i`, with `m` increasing from 0 to `ceil(n/2)` in steps of 1.

With the above conclusions we can first deduce the modified boundary condition, and thus the sum:

[image]

Collecting the terms together, after applying the last line (a standard result):

[image]

> Therefore the total complexity is
>
> [image]

---

EDIT: some numerical tests to prove this result. Code:

```
T = function(n) {
    var m = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i += 2)
       for (var j = 1; j <= n / 2; j *= 3)
          for (var k = i; k * k <= n; k++)
             m++;
    return m;
}
```

Plot of `T(n) / log(n)` against `n`:

[image]

Clearly linear to a *very* good margin of error, which proves that `T(n) = Θ(n log n)`.